# FB.ui permission request throws error : FB.Auth.setSession incompatible with OAuth2

Tags: oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am facing this issue currently with OAuth2.0 migration.While asking permissions using FB.ui ,I am getting this javascript error:

`FB.Auth.setSession incompatible with OAuth2.`

Same issue for `stream.publish` using `FB.api` method.

I do not want permissions using `FB.login`, because it opens up a pop up always.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change scope and perms for auth works gave me the new facebook and replace tokens. Notwithstanding facebook made ​​and returned to its previous state and all my work was in vain. It did so again now